# Does Slater's condition hold for this problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the following optimization problem.

$$ \min_{x,y} \quad cx+dy \quad \text{subject to} 
\quad e^x + e^y = 1 \tag{OP} \label{OP}$$

Given the lack of inequality constraints in \eqref{OP}, does [Slater's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition) hold trivially? Can I conclude there is a zero duality gap here?

Answer (score 3):

A Naga says, you can rewrite the equality constraint $h(x)=0$ as a pair of inequality constraints
$$h(x) \leq 0$$
$$-h(x) \leq 0$$

The Slater condition would require
$$h(x)<0$$
$$-h(x)<0$$
which is an impossibility. So the Slater condition cannot be true of a problem with equality constraints. Other regularity conditions may be usable though.

Comment: Your assertion regarding Slater's condition is false. It handles (linear) equality constraints just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the equality constraint as $\exp{x} + \exp{y} \leq 1$ and $-\exp{x} -\exp{y} \leq -1$. If slater conditions hold for this new formulation, (since the problem is convex), strong duality (gap zero) would follow.

Comment: Slater theorem works only one way, and there are many "constraint qualifications" beyond convexity of the constraints that can establish strong duality (Boyd and Vandenberghe). This problem doesn't obey slaters as pointed out by Jyotirmoy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what dual you are talking about. Your problem is not convex so in theory, the concept of duality gap doesn't apply. Moreover, Slater's condition is only for inequality contraints of the form $g(x) \geq 0$ where $g$ is a concave function. Slater's condition will be satisfied if there exists an $x$ such that $g(x) > 0$.

Comment: As far as I understand, duality gap is a valid notion even for non-convex primal problems. In fact, I don't see where in the formulation of dual problem, do we require primal problem to be convex.